# ask about size and how to solve it

Tags: fixed-gear

i just bought and build a BLB classic frameset. size 53 and im using 700x28c wheelset. but after that, my toe clip touching the front wheelset especially when i want to turn right or left. please help me to solve this prob.

Answer (score 2):

You have one of two things happening:

1. Your fork is on backwards
2. Your frame has toe overlap.

A backwards fork should be easy to resolve.

Toe overlap is common on many frames at low speeds. If thats what it is, you'll just have to get used to it. It's not really a big deal. See this [Touching the front wheel with my foot when turning](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13060/touching-the-front-wheel-with-my-foot-when-turning/13061#13061) for more info.